# Mayavi mlab moving object

Tags: python, rotation

I am a chemist, so programming isn't my daily work. However for one project, I am building a little programm on NMR product operators.

I have an vector with quiver, which always has its one point in [0,0,0] and just the head of the arrow is moveable, e.g. from the z to the y axis ([0,0,1] to [0,1,0]).

Right now I just can plot first the one vector and then the other. Is it possible to let the arrow rotate from one position to the other?